# c# client to consume OData with linq support

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-mvc-4, wcf-web-api

ASP.NET MVC4 Beta introduced an easy way to create OData endpoints using WebAPI.

So having the following controller:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET /api/values
    public IQueryable<Document> Get()
    {
        return (new[] { 
            new Document() { Info = "a", Title = "qwe1" }, 
            new Document() { Info = "b", Title = "qwe2" }, }).AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

I can query the data with url's like: *http://localhost:44087/api/values?$filter=Title eq 'qwe1'*

Is there a proper .net library that can consume this? So I could do something like:

```
new WebApiClient("http://localhost:44087/api/values")
                    .Get<Document>().Where(x=>x.Title == "qwe1").ToList()
```

Without specifying the `$filter=Title eq 'qwe1'` part manually?

Comment: If its a restful odata endpoint, you should be able to add a `Service Reference` from your calling project and VS will generate a proxy class for you.

Comment: it's not exactly a *restful odata endpoint* like WCF Data Service once. It's queryable like odata endpoint, but has no metadata, so adding a service reference doesn't work

Comment: Ah too bad. Was a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing I found so far is [netFX HttpEntityClient](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/querying-wcf-endpoints-using-web-api/).
Though, it looks pretty good, it sounds strange that I found nothing comparable from MS..